# How to get felica japanese IC card name like (Suica, ICOCA, Kitaca, PASMO, TOICA, manaca, PiTaPa, SUGOCA, nimoca, はやかけん, icsca, ...etc.)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nfc, core-nfc

How to get felica japanese IC card name like (Suica, ICOCA, Kitaca, PASMO, TOICA, manaca, PiTaPa, SUGOCA, nimoca, はやかけん, icsca, ...etc.) For iOS swift

- Currently I use https://github.com/treastrain/TRETJapanNFCReader this Libeary but they don't have support
- In android have this type of libeary: https://github.com/metrodroid/metrodroid

If anyone have idea about this So please share thoughts here....

I tried with NFC felica servicecode list but in this current code only four NFC F card identified.
All other card give a same serviceCode so is not helpful.